# Why does git pull update my remote repo?

Tags: git, git-pull

I made some changes, `git add`, `git commit`, and then `git pull --rebase`. My understanding is that when I `git pull rebase`, I'm adding all the code from the remote repo into my local repo and then adding my latest commit on top of that, without adding an additional commit (which merge would do). Thus, my index and working directory now reflects the latest code from the remote and what latest commit. This is on my **local** repo.

What I don't understand is why when I tried to push to the **remote** repo, git tells me everything is already up to date. I thought I've only updated my **local** repo, not my **remote** repo. Pulling updates just the **local**, not **remote** right?

Terminal after `git pull rebase`

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: commitmessage1
Applying: commitmessage2
Applying: commitmessage3
```

Terminal after `git push`

```
Counting objects: 39, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
Writing objects: 100% (39/39), 3.51 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 39 (delta 32), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: From jlei.com:master
remote:    75e79e6..f05460f  v2/updates -> origin/v2/updates
remote: Already up-to-date.
remote: Build skipped.
To user@jlei.com:master
   75e79e6..f05460f  v2/updates -> v2/updates
```

Comment: That's correct.  `git pull` does not make any changes to the remote repository.  If you think you are seeing different behavior, please put together a reproducible set of steps and include that in your question and it will be easier for us to help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: @larsks i've put in the terminal responses

Comment: Looks like you've got server-side hooks going on. Your push worked (`Writing objects: 100% (39/39), 3.51 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 39 (delta 32), reused 0 (delta 0)`), then more stuff happened, including another pull (looks like it's from jlei.com to origin, but I don't know what's producing that output)

Comment: @PaulHicks can you give me more information about server hooks?

Comment: **remote:    75e79e6..f05460f  v2/updates -> origin/v2/updates**
wouldn't this part mean the push? from the local to remote(origin)

Comment: They're little scripts that git runs for you on detecting certain events. Here's a link to [the book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Comment: @M.M yes, just fixed in edit